# Reshaping an ndarray for Support Vector Machines

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, svm

I wanted to use SVHN data and try SVM on it.

```
testdata['X'] <type 'numpy.ndarray'>


(testdata['X']).shape is (32, 32, 3, 26032)
```

the problem is that SVM needs a 2d array and mine is 4. 
That means i need to reshape it  i think.

I tried :

```
(testdata['X']).reshape(2)
```

gives me :

```
ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using reshape you need to use all the elements from the previous array in the new one, for instance if your dimensions are:

```
(testdata['X']).shape is (x1, x2, x3, x4)
```

you could use reshape in this way:

```
(testdata['X']).reshape(x1*x2*x3,x4)
```

or some other combinations depending on your needs